# Find area of shaded region - is the information insufficient?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, area

This brain teaser turned out to be a brain boggler.
As I am the type of math need that dwells on a single problem until it gas been solved ( and understood ).

I don't think there is enough information given to find the area of shaded region . I tried drawing lines to make congruent pieces of the shaded region in terms of a side of the square call it $x$. I was even attacking it with trig to see if angles given since there are many parallel sides,  but still no avail. Please help.

[image]

Comment: May I ask where this nice problem was found?

Comment: mickep maybe u would be so inclined to upvote my question ? and I believe it was on pint5$erest . it was wierd that no solution was on that site either , and no where to be found anywhere on the net ( I searched many different wordings on Google of the problem and found the empty set 

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By a recommendation of @King Tut, adding my comment as an answer:

Denote the longer projection of a white square side by $a$, and the shorter by $b$. Then $2a+b+a+b=13$ (left side of the big square) and $2b+2a−b+a=11$ (upper side). From that we get $b=2$ and $a=3$. Now, by Pythagoras' theorem, the area of a white square is $a^2+b^2=9+4=13$, hence the white area is $78$ and the shaded is $65$.

Answer (score 18):

Consider the following illustration:

[image]

Write top angle (smaller one) as $\theta$ and side of square as $s$. Then use the fact that projection of red and green lines add up to side lengths of rectangle.

In the image, green line is for first equation and red line for second.

$$(3s+s \tan(\theta)) \cos(\theta) = 11 \tag{1}$$

$$(3s+2s \tan(\theta)) \cos(\theta) = 13 \tag{2}$$

From here we get  $s \sin(\theta) = 2$ and $s \cos(\theta) =3 $. So $\tan(\theta) = \frac{2}{3}$. Then $s = \sqrt{13}$.

The required area is $13 \cdot 11 - 6s^2 = 13\cdot 5 = 65$

**Note**: The redline does not touch the upper side at corner. It is just meant to show that we have to take projection of this line along vertical side of length 13. Just to show that red line makes angle $\theta$ with vertical side.

Comment: looks sound.  but i was wondering if it can be done without any trig  as I geometry as well .that would be the best trig approach I'm thinking

Comment: Hmm, sounds interesting, I would also wish to see. This one came naturally though.

Comment: Denote the longer projection of a white square side by $a$, and the shorter by $b$. Then $2a + b + a + b = 13$ (left side of the big square) and $2b + 2a - b + a = 11$ (upper side), from which $b = 2$ and $a = 3$. Now, by Pythagoras' theorem, the area of a white square is $a^2 + b^2 = 9 + 4 = 13$, hence the white area is $78$ and the shaded is $65$.

Comment: @Kolya nice, that shows we only needed similarity and Pythagoras! Basically it's same as what I did but just I needlessly stuffed trigonometry.

Comment: @King Tut Of course it's based on your solution, just making it plausible for a Pythagoras :)

Comment: @Kolya No i didn't mean that, your answer is indeed original and I recommend adding it as a answer!

Comment: Nice. It means that the shaded area is as large as 5 white squares. I wonder if it's possible to cut this area in small pieces and rearrange them to get 5 squares.

Comment: King Tut,  how can u be sure the red line extends to top right corner of rectangle?

Comment: It does not. @randin. And we don't need it to. Figure may be misleading due to thick lines. Follow the answer!

Comment: I have edited to clarify.

Comment: u are right since the red line only contains the squares and opposite side of the small triangle to use trig on it .I saw two pairs of congruent shapes surrounding the squares .can you find them? I thought somehow that would be useful but it wasn't.  I'm still wondering if their is another way to do this one but yours was about as clever as it can get  .or is,there another one ? 

Comment: @Randin Oh you are talking about the shapes on the right top and bottom (shaded ones)? I see now! Three such shapes are indeed similar, let me try, ive got some work, ill be back in some hours.